# RoR: How can I select a single image out of many uploaded images and make it a profile picture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, image, carrierwave, dropzone.js

I have just added an image section for a user where they can upload multiple images. I used carrierwave and dropzonejs. everything worked. I have profile model and Image model. profile has_many :images and image belongs to profile.

Usually I would have a carrierwave uploader just for profile pictures. but now that I have these images already, is there a way i can set it up so that i can select a single image as the user profile picture from those images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `profile_picture_id` attribute in your `Profile` model in which you can save an image id which will serve as the profile picture or you can add an attribute named `profile_picture` in the `Image` model which will be a boolean attribute with default value `false` so if the image is profile picture then just set it to `true`.

The above is just how you can store it on the backend you have to create a view where the user will select a single picture which will be the profile picture.

Hope this helps.